# Export Swagger end-points as single json file

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I have got a Java 8 Spring project that already has swagger configured to auto generate the swagger web-page documentation. 
I would like to also generate a single json file that contains all endpoints every time that  project builds.

Is there a way to generate this using Java annotations or XML/property from Swagger or Spring?

Comment: you can take a look at https://springfox.github.io/springfox/, i use this to generate my swagger docs

Comment: Why can't you go to `my-app/swagger.json` to get the json response of your end points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an automatic way provided by Swagger or Spring for customized fields, but there is a direct translation from swagger.yml to swagger.json. 
To resolve my problem, that needs only custom fields, I used Swagger Parser to serialize the fields that I wanted into a json file. It is far from ideal, but It did work.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't generate json file with annotation. But you can do it in @SpringBootTest. When the test run, do request to port on which server started, retrieve api docs and write them to file.